# Unable to load the JSON file

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Following is the json & js file code, unable to run the json file with jquery ajax, always showing error msg.

Running code on the loacl machine without any asp.net / php coding, I want to run JSON without the server. I have set the url through IIS on my local machine.

JSON:

```
//myTutorials.json file
{
  "one": "Singular sensation",
  "two": "Beady little eyes",
  "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
}
```

Javascript:

```
//main.js file
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: "myTutorials.json",
      format: "json",
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(response){      
        alert(response.one);
        alert('success');
      },
      error:function(){
        alert('error');
      }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>HTML5 responsive website tutorial</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Baumans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script>
</script>
<style>
</style>

<!-- my files -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="clickHeading"></div>
        <div id="id01"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: AJAX call requires the HTTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jozef pointed out, if you don't have a web server you can't request the file with ajax-function. However you can just use the json as a variable and test it out if that is enough for your need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var myJson = {
      "one": "Singular sensation",
      "two": "Beady little eyes",
      "three": "Little birds pitch by my doorstep"
    };  

    alert(myJson.one);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you.